# Android ImageGridview on ActivityForResult export to PDF

Tags: android, gridview, itext, universal-image-loader

I´m using the "universal image loader 1.9.0" to display a gridview of user selected images on an Activity with a ActivityForResult Intent. Android version tested on android:minSdkVersion="16"

main . java

```
private void initImageLoader() {
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
            new WeakMemoryCache());

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);
}
```

main . xml

```
 <ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="315dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridGallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="-15dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="-15dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/gallery_item" >
    </GridView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSinglePick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/noimageavailable" />
</ViewSwitcher>
```

This Activity is an Input form, the user must fill the requested data on some EditText fields and add some images. 
Then, the user can print this form to .PDF (I´m using iText Library for that).

I just implement the iText lib, so I can print on .pdf the form, but I can´t figure it out, how can I export the gridview to pdf.

```
public void makeAndSharePDF(View v) {

    Document documento = new Document();

    try {
        File f = crearFichero(NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO);
        FileOutputStream ficheroPdf = new FileOutputStream(
                f.getAbsolutePath());
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, ficheroPdf);
        documento.open();

        Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.logomail);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image imagen = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        imagen.scalePercent(75);
                    PdfPTable tabla_header = new PdfPTable(2);
                    tabla_header.setWidthPercentage(100);

                    PdfPCell logo_header = new PdfPCell();
                    logo_header.addElement(new Chunk(imagen, 0, 0));
                    logo_header.setRowspan(2);
                    logo_header.setBorder(0); 
                    logo_header.setPadding(10);
                    tabla_header.addCell(logo_header);

                    PdfPCell titulo_reporte = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("titulo reporte", font_titulo));

                  titulo_reporte.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                  titulo_reporte.setBorder(0); 
                  titulo_reporte.setPadding(10);
                  tabla_header.addCell(titulo_reporte);

                    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
                    String formattedDate = df.format(date.getTime());
                    PdfPCell fecha_reporte = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(formattedDate, font_subtitulo1));
                    fecha_reporte.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    fecha_reporte.setBorder(0); 
                    fecha_reporte.setPadding(10);
                    tabla_header.addCell(fecha_reporte);

                    documento.add(tabla_header);

    } catch (DocumentException e) {

        Log.e(ETIQUETA_ERROR, e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e(ETIQUETA_ERROR, e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        documento.close();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/foldername"+"/filename.pdf");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

1. How can I get the paths of the images to export them to the pdf file? or, how can I export the gridview to the pdf file?
2. How can I improve this code, I mean, I trigger the pdf file with a button on the xml file, so, I have all the iText code inside my main class. How can I trigger the pdf file from another class, I want this code outside the main class.
3. The image on the first cell is totally ruined, is there a way to improve that too?

Thanks guys.